# Java one to many persist hashset

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

Can someone guide me I am getting reportFilter empty when I send a request from postman. 'Name' field is properly set BUT report Filter is null. I am missing any annotation on OneToMany? I am calling /api/save which takes ReportTemplate object but I am not getting reportFilter List in that object

```
@Entity
@Audited
@XmlRootElement
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer" })
public class ReportTemplate {
 private String name;
 private String templateFormat;
 private Set<ReportFilter> reportFilter = new HashSet<>();

 @NotNull
 public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="reportTemplate")
 @JsonIgnore
 public Set<ReportFilter> getReportFilter() {
    return reportFilter;
 }

  public void setReportFilter(Set<ReportFilter> reportFilter) {
    this.reportFilter = reportFilter;
  }
}

@Entity
@Audited
@XmlRootElement
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"column_1", "reportTemplate_id"}))
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer" })
public class ReportFilter {

private String column_1;
private ReportTemplate reportTemplate;

 @NotNull
 public String getColumn_1() {
    return column_1;
 }

 public void setColumn_1(String column_1) {
    this.column_1 = column_1;
 }

 @ManyToOne
 @NotNull
 public ReportTemplate getReportTemplate() {
    return reportTemplate;
 }

 public void setReportTemplate(ReportTemplate reportTemplate) {
    this.reportTemplate = reportTemplate;
 }
}
```

Postman request:

```
{
    "name": "Test-Report",
    "reportFilter": [
        {
            "filterColumn": "Reference Number",
            "column_1": "A",
            "columnValue": "HE222",
        },
        {
            "filterColumn": "Test Column",
            "column_1": "B",
            "columnValue": "1234",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you thing JsonIgnore does? Here's its documentation: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html. BTW, your entities don't have any ID. That's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem resolves by deleting `@JsonIgone` from these piece of code:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="reportTemplate")
public Set<ReportFilter> getReportFilter() {
   return reportFilter;
}
```

with this anntotaion you say to `JsonEncoderDecoder` that ignore this property when converting from json object to hibernate entity.

Also you missed `@JoinColumn` on the one side of relation between two entites. use somthing like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TEMPLATE_ID")
@NotNull
public ReportTemplate getReportTemplate() {
    return reportTemplate;
}
```

you need this to define the owner entity.

And also all entities MOST have one `@Id` column for primary key.